# PostBack not fireing in window.onbeforeunload with Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, postback, onbeforeunload

I have a main page that contains frames

```
    function attachToTheSaveWhenLeave(sender) {
    sender.onbeforeunload = function (ev) {
        sender.Save();
    };
}
<frameset cols="25%,75%">
    <frame id ="Frame1" src="LeftFrame.aspx" />
    <frame id ="frmTest" src="FrameContent.aspx" />
</frameset>
```

In one of the page contained by a frame(FrameContent.aspx), I need to know if the page is discarded in order to fire a PostBack and the server must save the changes made by the user

```
var isPostBack = false;

window.onload = function (ev) {
    window.parent.attachToTheSaveWhenLeave(window);
}

function Save() {
    if (!isPostBack)
        $("input:submit")[0].click();
}
 <form id="formFrame" runat="server" onsubmit="isPostBack=true;">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

In IE the server receives the postback but with Firefox I have to use setTimeOut for this to work

```
function Save() {
    if (!isPostBack)
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("input:submit")[0].click();
      },1);
}
```

I do not like the solution I have found, and I do not understand the Firefox's behavior.
Can anyone explain to me why is Firefox behaving this way and if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an alternate for you, but Firefox appears to be behaving as documented (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload). The point of onbeforeunload is just to put up a prompt when navigating away from a page.

Perhaps jquery.unload (http://api.jquery.com/unload/) or window.onunload is what you had in mind.